# Django use `super(child,self)`instead of `super()` in latest version

Tags: django, python-3.x

In Django 1.11 tutorial and documentation,there's codes style as `super(child,self)` everywhere.
for instance:

```
return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
```

What's the advantage of it? to reminder you in the current class for memory?

Comment: This is not unique to Django, and is just how python's `super()` method works - that signature is required in Python 2 and optional in Python 3. You can read more about it at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function.

Comment: Note that Django 2.0 drops support for Python 2, so the [docs for 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) have been simplified to use `super()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compatible with projects running python2.